# Control webview content from C# button

Tags: c#, html, webview, win-universal-app

I'm working on my first universal app. It's a simple webview but I would like to "control" it with some native buttons.
For example I have this html div:

```
<div id="country-change">
  <i data-parameter="sessionCity" data-title="Scegli" class="fa fa-pencil change-location">Cambia</i>
</div>
```

Or

```
<a href="/me/tickets" data-animation="none" class="icon note">
 I miei biglietti
```

I can't access the full code because the webpage that I'm loading in the webview is not mine (I just know that clicking this div I do something, the Javascript code behind that, at first sight, looks like spaghetti code for me), but what I'm trying to do is to simulate a click in the webview pressing a C#/XAML button. I tried with the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
private async void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await view.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new String[] { "window.location = document.getElementsByClassName('icon note').href" });
    }
```

Could you help me? Is it possible to simulate a click in the webview with some magic C# code? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do some search before asking a question. Anyway, Here's the possible solution.

```
await view.InvokeScriptAsync("eval",new String[] {"document.getElementById("your control's id").click();"});
```